# R - repeat static 1st argument and iterate through 2nd of cor.test in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

**Task:** I have numerical data in a large `data.table` in R (columns 1:3 are character columns of identifiers); I would like to perform `cor.test()` where the 1st argument is static (a single column) whilst the 2nd argument iterates through multiple columns.

**Info:** For the processing to be as time-efficient as possible I would like to perform this in the `j` parameter of the `data.table` ( `DT[i, j, by]` ), unless there are even quicker methods (e.g. would `cor.test()` within a `for` loop in the `foreach` and `doparallel` libraries be quicker, or could this even be implemented within the `data.table itself` ?).

However, my attempt returns an error (see below). I can also `transpose()` the data if required. I appreciate any help offered.

**Code:**

```r
# Install data.table package if not installed and load
if (!require("data.table")) {
  install.packages("data.table")
  library(data.table)
  }

# Data (example)
head(DT, n=2)

#>     ID     info1  info2  name1  name2  name3  name4
#>     <char> <char> <char> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1:  A100   StuffA StuffB 0.1460 NA     -0.019 0.2102
#> 2:  A101   StuffA StuffC 0.0987 -1.307 -0.174 NA

# Perform correlation test
result <- DT[, cor.test(DT[, "name2"], DT[, 4:ncol(DT)], method = c("pearson"))]
```

**Error:**

```r
> Error in cor.test.default(DT[, "name2"], DT[, 4:ncol(DT)], method = c("pearson")) : 
>   'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

**Additional attempts:**

```r
# Other attempts to achieve this include:

# 1: lapply() within data.table, returns same error as above
result <- DT[, lapply(.SD, cor.test("name2", 4:ncol(DT)))]

# 2: mapply(), attempt to repeat the single column to get the same dimensions
result <- mapply(function(x, y) cor.test(x, y, method = c("pearson")),
                 x = cbind(rep(DT[, "name2"], times = ncol(DT)-3)),
                 y = DT[, 4:ncol(DT)])
```

Comment: You don't provide an exact example, but do you want something like this maybe? `DT <- as.data.table(iris[-5]); DT[, Map(cor.test, .(Sepal.Width), .SD, method="pearson"), .SDcols=-1]`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail and @Ronak Shah, I've edited my original post to provide more information and hopefully read clearer. Initially I did not include my other failed attempts as I wanted the fastest implementation (which as I understand can be achieved with the ```data.table``` library over the ```apply``` family of functions or ```dplyr```) and was trying to avoid posts correcting those slower attempts.

Comment: Not sure what you want as a result, but you can get *a result* like: `DT[, Map(cor.test, .(name2), .SD), .SDcols=4:ncol(DT)]`

Comment: Thanks again @thelatemail. It performs quickly, but I can see that the result is not quite what I was hoping for. I was aiming to extract the ```estimate``` and ```p.value``` of the ```cor.test``` for each comparison with each column iteration, e.g. ```result$estimate``` ;  I think usually the result of ```cor.test``` is a multi-level list, so this data.table result is a suprise, I'm not sure how I could extract the necessary information from it.

Comment: @BuzzB - with some tweaking to the function, you should be able to do something like `DT[, Map(function(s,r) cor.test(s,r)[c("estimate","p.value")], .SD, .(name2)), .SDcols=4:ncol(DT)]`

Comment: @thelatemail - Thanks, that's great! But due to the ```estimate``` values in the ```cor.test``` output being stored in the list level ```cor``` below ```estimate```, the above code produces content in the format ```c(cor = -0.0112)``` instead of the value on its own. I can extract that value like this: ```DT[, Map(function(s,r) cor.test(s,r)[["estimate"]][["cor"]], .SD, .(name2)), .SDcols=4:ncol(DT)]```. However, it seems inefficient to have to perform the entire process again modifying it to append ```cor.test(s,r)[["p.value"]]``` and store that as a second object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @thelatemail who provided the solution (see comments of original post).

I added to it to produce the below code which extracts the values from the `cor.test`.

```r
resDT <- DT[, Map(function(s,r) cor.test(s,r, method = "pearson")
                  [c("estimate","p.value")], .SD, .(name2)), .SDcols=4:ncol(DT)]

estimateVal <- unlist(resDT[1], use.names = FALSE)
pVal <- unlist(resDT[2], use.names = FALSE)
```